# How to measure the properties of a non-newtonian fluid?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

We have made non-newtonian fluid by mixing water (or Tonic) and starch. We can't figure out the link between the amount of water and starch and the viscosity of the fluid.

What we can figure out is that we add less water, there is less force required to make the fluid solid.

Could you describe a experiment that describes the whole process of measuring the viscosity.
In addition to this, we would like to measure the force you need to push on the fluid to keep it solid. We tried putting weights in a cup and letting it sink into the fluid, but the cup always sinks into the fluid. No matter how much weight is added. The time it sunk into the fluid stayed the same.